# Yaml variable to store result of sfdx command

Tags: salesforcedx, force, variable, gitlab

Throughout execution yaml file for CI/CD process in GitLab I am using `sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT id FROM UserRole where name='CER' " -t -u qwerty@mycompany.org` to find proper id for UserRole CER (as result i catch id). I want to assign this value to some variable and after that use it in next sfdx command (replace RoleId)
`- sfdx force:data:record:update -s User -u qwerty@mycompany.org -w "Name='User User'" -v "UserRoleId=RoleId"` .

Please tell me how this can be done? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do this with an Anonymous Apex script instead.

```
update new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId(), RoleId = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Name = 'CER'].Id);
```

The run it with [`force:apex:execute`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm).

Comment: Could you explain.

Comment: @SFguru What specifically are you asking?

Comment: Could you explain.
1) SFDX command - sfdx force:apex:execute -f /user/Role.cls -u qwerty@mycompany.org
2) How use this in Apex class (how it works for you - do we need some special things) - I am trying change/set custom Role for scratch org admin.

Comment: There is no Apex class involved. You just need to place code like what I showed above. in a file and run it with the `sfdx force:apex:execute` command in your pipeline. The command in your comment appears to be correct.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Nice solution!